# Need to find MAX value from between two auction dates

Tags: mysql

So I have the following which works correctly.

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemDescription, BidStartingPrice, BuyItNowPrice, AuctionDate
FROM ITEM
WHERE AuctionDate BETWEEN '2017-11-07' AND '2017-11-22'
```

I would now like to find the MAX bid starting price from the answer given above.

How can I go about and achieving this as I have not been successful in obtaining a correct `MAX` which comes from the above. What is happening is that whenever I try to find the `MAX` I get the `MAX` but not from those results which are between those two dates.

Comment: order by bidstartingprice desc limit 1

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) if you want more informations like this :

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemDescription, MAX(BidStartingPrice)
FROM ITEM 
WHERE AuctionDate BETWEEN '2017-11-07' AND '2017-11-22'
GROUP BY ItemID, ItemDescription
```

If you only want the maximum BidStartingPrice this should work

```
SELECT MAX(BidStartingPrice)
FROM ITEM 
WHERE AuctionDate BETWEEN '2017-11-07' AND '2017-11-22'
```

Comment: Hi  Fleury, thanks so much, yeah the second one was what I was looking for. Thanks mate, really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help! And welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted @A.Attard

Comment: Thank you, glad to be here :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(BidStartingPrice) FROM ITEM WHERE AuctionDate BETWEEN '2017-11-07' AND '2017-11-22';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.